# Memory occupy by variable

Tags: java

When a variable is initialized time and again do it occupy fresh memory at each initialization.

Is this the reason why in a for loop initialization occurs only once at time of starting of loop because if variable is initialized at every next loop.it will occupy a lot of space in RAM.

Comment: It depends where it is declared. If it's method-local, which is what you seem to be asking about, it goes into the same stack slot every time around the loop. Your question appears to assume that language implementors are utterly incompetent and that you're the first person who's ever thought of this issue. They aren't, and you're not.

Comment: Wow, what a nice way to welcome someone to SO, @EJP. It's not the most well-formulated question but I don't see anything in there that implies that he thinks he's come up with something novel; he's just checking his understanding by asking whether something works the way he thinks it might.

Comment: @alexroussos I disagree completely. The fact that he is asking whether it will consume infinite RAM on repetition indicates exactly the opposite.

Comment: I exactly mean what alexroussos wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in Java only have two types, primitives and references.

For local variables, these are typically placed on the stack and often exist only in registers (for leaf methods)  These occupy the same memory each time they are reused and if a method exits and called again, the same memory is used.

However when you create a `new` object, this will be on the heap and typically, every time you call `new` it really does create a new object. (It can be optimised away but rarely is)  So yes, if you decide to create lots of objects, there is a good chance you will use lots of memory and possibly create lots of garbage.

Answer (score 0):

***Is this the reason why in a for loop initialization occurs only once
at time of starting of loop***

```
In case of for-loop When the loop first starts, the initialization portion of 
the loop is executed. 
Generally, this is an expression that sets the value of the loop control 
variable,which acts as a counter that controls the loop.It usually tests the
loop control variable against a target value. If this expression is true,
then the body of the loop is executed. If it is false, the loop terminates.

Hence from this you can understand that there is no need to initialize 
the variable again in for-loop just incrementing it does the work.
```